# Can Macaulay2 detect if an element has the strong/weak Lefschetz property?

Tags: commutative-algebra, macaulay2

Let $A$ be a graded Artinian ring. An element $r$ of degree $i$ has the strong Lefschetz property if multiplication by $r$ on each graded component, $A_d \xrightarrow{r} A_{d+i}$ is of full rank possible given the size of $A_{d}$ and $A_{d+i}$, i.e., is injective or surjective.

Does Macualay2 already have a method to test if an element has the strong Lefschetz property? This seems like something I can probably code by hand (at least in the basic cases where I want it), but it also seems like something that would already exist!

**Edit:**
I made something that I'm sure is not as efficient as it could be, that I will leave up in case someone else has this question some day (or in case it can be obviously improved).

Given a module M and an element r, I think this will return if r is Lefschetz on M or not:

```
i=(degree r)_0
maxDeg=(degree numerator reduceHilbert hilbertSeries M)_0;
    lefschetz=true;
    for j from 0 to maxDeg do(
        f=r*basis(j,M)//basis(j+i,M); 
        lefschetz = lefschetz or (((isInjective f) or (isSurjective f)));)
```

Comment: I think your code assumes $\deg r = 1$. You might also try [here](https://github.com/LisaNicklasson/MaximalRankProperties-Macaulay2-package) (disclaimer: I have not personally tried this)

Comment: @math54321 aha you're right, good point. I was using it only in the situation I needed, which was deg r=1, but I've edited it now. Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for!